# How to skip lines in Camel csv parsing

Tags: csv, apache-camel

This is a route. But in csv file there are 3 useless lines - 1,2 and the last one. How i can to skip them in my route?

```
<route id="generateOrder-route">  

        <from uri="file:G://data?noop=true"/>
        <unmarshal>
            <csv skipFirstLine="true"/>
        </unmarshal>
        <split>
            <simple>${body}</simple>
               <transform>
                <method ref="orderBean" method="generateOrder"/>
               </transform>
            <to ref="sqlInsertBalance" />
        </split>
      </route>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use a filter processor :

```
<route id="generateOrder-route">  
    <from uri="file:G://data?noop=true"/>
    <unmarshal>
        <csv skipFirstLine="true"/>
    </unmarshal>
    <split>
        <filter>
            <simple>${header.CamelSplitIndex} &gt; 2</simple>
            <pipeline>
                <simple>${body}</simple>
                <transform>
                  <method ref="orderBean" method="generateOrder"/>
                </transform>
                <to ref="sqlInsertBalance" />
            </pipeline>
        </filter>
    </split>
  </route>
```